# Count sequence by date in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame as:

```
Data_c       User  Rank  sequence_in_progress

 15-03-2017   2     0         0
 15-03-2017   1     1         0
 16-03-2017   2     0         0
 17-03-2017   2     1         0
 18-03-2017   1     0         0
```

Now I would substitute in "sequence_in_progress" within the Data Frame , exploring it, the sequence taking into accout the date of join and the user who has joined.

Basically, the result should be :

```
  Data_c     User  Rank  sequence_in_progress

 15-03-2017   2     0         1
 15-03-2017   1     1         1
 16-03-2017   2     0         2
 17-03-2017   2     1         3
 18-03-2017   1     0         2
```

Basically, "sequence_in_progress" represents the sequence in which an user "x" has choosen something in a given date considering.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
Note that this solution works for an arbitrary number of users.

```
cc = ['Data_c', 'User', 'Rank']
vals = [['15-03-2017',   2,     0],
         ['15-03-2017',   1,     1],
         ['16-03-2017',   2,     0],
         ['17-03-2017',   2,     1],
         ['18-03-2017',   1,     0]]

frame = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = cc)

# Crete the sequence (1,...,N) for each user
users_sequence = [group.assign(sequence = range(1, len(group)+1))
                        for key, group  in frame.groupby('User')]

# Put everything together, using reindex to have same order as the original frame 
result = pd.concat(users_sequence, axis = 0).reindex(frame.index) 

       Data_c  User  Rank  sequence
0  15-03-2017     2     0         1
1  15-03-2017     1     1         1
2  16-03-2017     2     0         2
3  17-03-2017     2     1         3
4  18-03-2017     1     0         2
```